# Calling jQuery in Ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to call a jQuery function that acts upon a form in AJAX response.

How do I do it???

**jQuery Function**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $("#load_timetable").on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "load_timetable.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:  new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $("#time_table").html(data);
      },
      error: function() {}          
    });
  });
});
```

**Another AJAX Function**

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-viewFacultyDialog", function () {
  var uid = $(this).data('id');
  $('#update').click(function() {    
    var ajaxRequest;
    try { 
      ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) { 
      try { 
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
      }
      catch (e) {
        try { 
          ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        }
        catch (e) { 
          alert("Your browser broke!"); 
          return false; 
        }
      }
    }
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
        **//I would like to call JQUERY here**
        document.getElementById("update_action_response").innerHTML = "";
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('update_action_response');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
      }
    }
    var dept_slot = document.getElementById('dept_slot').value;
    var subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
    var faculty1 = document.getElementById('faculty1').value;
    var faculty2 = document.getElementById('faculty2').value;
    var faculty3 = document.getElementById('faculty3').value;

    var queryString="?id="+uid+"&dept_slot="+dept_slot+"&subject="+subject+"&faculty1="+faculty1+"&faculty2="+faculty2+"&faculty3="+faculty3;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "update_timetable.php"+queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
  });
});
```

In simple I would like to reload the contents after updation without page reload by submitting the same parameters that are used to load the contents before update.

Comment: Hi, try to change (in the first function) the new FormData to serialize($('form')).

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise method which is already defined in jquery.you can use it if data transfer successfully. such that if promise returns true then perform this task.else other task.